Le service de Sèvres à l'N (in 19th century novel)
The second sentence of Edmond de Goncourt's Chérie (published 1884) begins

Des fleurs sur la table, les domestiques en mollets, le service de Sèvres à l'N couronné en or [...]

I'm not sure about le service de Sèvres à l'N - does that mean something like stamped with the letter N, referencing a particular set of dishes that presumably meant something to readers in the 19th century?

Yes. Even without more context, the sentence is clearly about un service (en porcelaine) de Sèvres where plates and dishes have a letter N painted in gold on them.
As the book was published in 1884, the N couronné could be related to Napoleon III who was Emperor of the French from 1852 until he was deposed on 4 September 1870 (source wikipedia).

A majuscule N, the Imperial crown above, within twigs of laurel and oak. Like this https://image.invaluable.com/housePhotos/MonteCarlo/60/758260/H5211-L351471934_original.jpg
